# Python in Selenium Automation

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am trying to run selenium by running the below two lines of code after giving the path to chromedriver..

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/chromedriver")
```

But its not working and displaying the below error.

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

Can you please tell how to fix it ?

Comment: Try to add ChromeOptions -> 

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/chromedriver", options=webdriver.ChromeOptions())

Answer (score 1):

Check your chrome brower version and download chromedriver accordingly from below url https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r" path of chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('your url')
```

Comment: You can use ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 its compatible with 80.0.3987.149

Comment: from the about tab,i found the chrome version to be Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit). Hence i clicked on the Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit) tab and i downloaded the chromedriver_win32.zip..I kept it in desktop and i ran the code as shown below   



from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/chromedriver") 
browser.get('google.com/')

Comment: What's the error now also you have to specify correct path C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/chromedriver.exe

Comment: fI kept the chromedriver.exe in desktop inside a folder named sriyam and then i ran the code,but its showing the same error.   

from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\sriyam\chromedriver.exe")

The error showing is "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\sriyam\chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1

Comment: try below code :::

from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\sriyam\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
driver.get('your url')

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing some libraries, i had a similar problem when i was trying stuff with selenium. try installing the chromium driver as well cause it might have the libraries you need, even if you don't want to use chromium

Comment: It worked well when i unblocked the chromedriver from the K7 antivirus settings..Thanks anyways..